# I only have Office 2013. How do I access a Sharepoint 2010 Workspace?

Tags: office-integration, office, workspace, sharepoint-workspace

When I only have Office 2013 available to me, is there still a way to sync with a Sharepoint 2010 Workspace for offline access? e.g. will skydrive pro work with a Sharepoint 2010 Workspace? Or some other method?

Or is it the case that I still must have an Office 2010 files & license for the Sharepoint Workspace 2010 client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that OneDrive (formerly known as SkyDrive Pro) will not sync with a SharePoint 2010 server. The MS KB article 2904784 points out that if you intend to sync with a SharePoint 2010 server then you must use SharePoint 2010 Workspace for folder sync. OneDrive (SkyDrive) has been coded to disallow syncing between OneDrive and SharePoint 2010.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2904784

Answer (score -1):

As you know, [SharePoint Workspace is deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178954%28v=office.15%29) in 2013 but they do offer a workaround with [Folder Sync in Office 2013](http://www.pallareviews.com/1113/sharepoint-2013-office-15-skydrive-sync-now-capabilities/).  Is this not working for you?